# Using Inline CSS to style div's?

Tags: html, css, inline

I have been having some trouble with some text in the footer of my page. In my external style sheet

text is aligned to the left by default. but it was my understanding that Inline CSS would overide this. here is what I have done with my code:

```
<div  id="footer" style="text-align: center; ">
    <p>Created by John Smith<br>Copyright "Microsoft Inc." 2015</p>
</div>
```

However the text still appears on the left of the page, what is my error here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well its working perfectly. Ex- https://jsfiddle.net/xg9n9Ln3/

Comment: That's so strange on my site it still appears to be aligning to the left: http://imgur.com/wJct0FR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi now used to this

```
<div  id="footer" >
    <p style="text-align: center; ">Created by John Smith<br>Copyright "Microsoft Inc." 2015</p>
</div>
```

Now `p` is block level `element` so than you can apply to `css` `p` tag

2nd option if you used to external CSS
used to this in external CSS as like this

```
#footer>p{text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Thanks for this it never occured to me to apply the style to the paragraph rather than the div.

Comment: than you can used to this css #footer>p{text-align:center;}

Answer (score 0):

To make later declaration override the previous declaration:

```
/* 0: default */

#footer { text-align:left; }
#footer { text-align:center; }

/* 1: using !important */

#footer { text-align:left; }
#footer { text-align:center !important; }

/* 2: specific selector */

#footer { text-align:left; }
#mainpage #footer { text-align:center; }

/* 3: selector type tag - id - class */

div { text-align:right; }
div.footer { text-align:left; }
div#footer { text-align:center; }
```

The style that has the highest CSS specificity is applied. The specificity of different elements is defined as follows:

```
!important = is the superior: only !important can override !important
ID attribute = 100
Class attribute = 10
Element = 1

<p id="target" class="target">Hello World</p>

<style>
p#target {color: black} /* Specificity: 101 */
p#target {color: red} /* Specificity: 101 */
p.target {color: blue} /* Specificity: 11 */
p {color: tomato} /* Specificity: 1 */
/* Red color is applied */
</style>
```

**Keep these rules in mind:**

```
.contents {color: #999 !important;}

section.contents {color: #999;}

body .contents {color: #999;}

#container > .contents {color: #999;}
```

Credit: CSS Rule Priorities: https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/web/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Try this code in an external style sheet.